# Split linestrings at pairwise intersections

Tags: r, sf, linestring

I have a set of line strings in a single `sf` object R which I want to turn into a (sf)network. Not in all cases are the intersections marked. So I want to transform the left data to the right, dividing each new line at the intersection points. Each new part getting the attributes of the line it belonged to.

[image: Splitting two crossing lines into four line segments, keeping attributes for each.]

The package authors of sfnetwork [use `break` from the `v.clean` toolset in GRASS GIS](https://r-spatial.org/r/2019/09/26/spatial-networks.html), which I don't have access to. I could iterate over all intersections in the dataset and do some manipulation of those that cross, but that sounds horribly cumbersome for a task which I would assume is frequent enough that someone has solved it properly in R.

Comment: The sfnetworks package defines an ad-hoc morpher to split linestrings at shared internal boundary points. See [here](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/articles/sfn02_preprocess_clean.html#smooth-pseudo-nodes-1) for more details. On the other hand, if you need to split linestrings at all line intersections, you should check [lwgeom::st_split](https://r-spatial.github.io/lwgeom/reference/st_split.html) and the discussion [here](https://github.com/luukvdmeer/sfnetworks/issues/134).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure how well it scales with larger networks but the following does what you are asking

```r
library(sf)

ls1 = st_sfc(st_linestring(matrix(c(0,1,0,1), ncol = 2)))
ls2 = st_sfc(st_linestring(matrix(c(0,1,1,0), ncol = 2)))
ls = c(ls1, ls2)
ls = st_as_sf(ls)
ls$v = c("v1", "v2")
ls$col = c("blue", "red")
ls
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 1 ymax: 1
#> CRS:           NA
#>                       x  v  col
#> 1 LINESTRING (0 0, 1 1) v1 blue
#> 2 LINESTRING (0 1, 1 0) v2  red
plot(st_geometry(ls), axes = T, col = 3:4, lwd = 3)
```

[image]

```r
p <- st_collection_extract(st_intersection(ls), "POINT")
q <- lwgeom::st_split(ls, p)
q <- st_collection_extract(q, "LINESTRING")

plot(st_geometry(q), axes = T, col = 1:4, lwd = 3)
```

[image]

```r
q
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 1 ymax: 1
#> CRS:           NA
#>      v  col                         x
#> 1   v1 blue LINESTRING (0.5 0.5, 1 1)
#> 1.1 v1 blue LINESTRING (0 0, 0.5 0.5)
#> 2   v2  red LINESTRING (0.5 0.5, 1 0)
#> 2.1 v2  red LINESTRING (0 1, 0.5 0.5)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: With `ls2 = st_sfc(st_linestring(matrix(c(0,1,0.75,0), ncol = 2)))` it does not work because of numerical innaccuracies. Maybe check out `st_snap`

Answer (score 4):

In my particular case, I did not only have individual line strings, but a full network of them. For that kind of structure, the [sfnetworks](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/) has been written – and it has a specific morpher [`to_spatial_subdivision`](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/reference/spatial_morphers.html), so following the [corresponding tutorial step](https://luukvdmeer.github.io/sfnetworks/articles/preprocess_and_clean.html#subdivide-edges), the relevant code is

```
network <- as_sfnetwork(linestrings) %>%
  activate(edges) %>%
  arrange(edge_length()) %>%
  convert(to_spatial_subdivision)
```

which seems to be implemented much more efficiently than the combination of

```
p <- st_collection_extract(st_intersection(ls), "POINT")
q <- lwgeom::st_split(linestrings, p)
q <- st_collection_extract(q, "LINESTRING")
```

which @JRR describes in his answer. On my graph with 26000 nodes and 30000 edges, `to_spatial_subdivision` takes a few seconds, while the
`st_intersection` on its own takes a dozen minutes.